# Sharepoint Foundation 2013 Recycle bin cannot see deleted item

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, administration, recycle-bin

The title is similar to other problems with Recycle bin but I'm not found the answer to them. Correctly if I'm wrong.

I'm the admin on our Sharepoint (Foundation 2013), (new at all of the SharePoint) and before two days one user accidentally deleted one document from the document library. 
I was looking in Recycle bin under Site collection, but it wasn't there.
I also looked in second stage Recycle bin (in Central Administration), but also wasn't there.

Strange to me is that I don't see the link to Recycle bin under Setting of web place under Administration of web place, why isn't Recycle Bin there and how can I add it here ?

[image]

[image]

Sorry because my picture is on Croatian language, but that's our SharePoint, on Croatian.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible reasons for that:

- You didn't look at the correct site, Recycle Bin in SharePoint is site-specific, a document deleted from `http://myportal/mainsites/site1` will not appear in the top-level site’s `http://myportal/mainsite/` Recycle Bin.
- Recycle Bin is not only site-specific, it is also specific for each user. Thus the Recycle Bin contents you see is limited to documents, items, lists and libraries that you’ve deleted, content deleted by other users does not show up here as I think.
- Recycle Bin does not keep deleted items forever. The default setting in SharePoint is to keep content in Recycle Bin for 30 days

You should also make sure that the recycle bin setting has been set correctly by following :

> Open Central Administration > Application Management > Manage web application > Select your web application > from the above ribbon select > general settings > check the setting of recycle bin status > make sure it's `On`.

Also, check others settings beside Recycle Bin.

[image]

Comment: In Central Administration is everywhere Recycle bin set as On, see my updated answer. But because I'm Admin, doesn't I then can't see everyones Recycle ..... I'm confused

Comment: Is this issue for specific user or file ?! should you try to delete dummy file and check if it's a general issue or not ? although what's the latest CU update that already installed on your farm ?

Comment: I tried delete some files and restore them, they ware in Rec. that's ok , but only this one file - nothing more special then others I can't found, don't understand why. We used then file from Arhive, but I'm asking in case if this happens again., what then ....

Comment: How much time has passed between when it was deleted and when you tried to recover it, maybe it was enough time to be permanently deleted. Also, are you sure it is a file and not an app. If the document library is empty and you deleted it you do not necessarily see it in the recycle bin

Comment: No. it was file, and time was 10 minutes after deleting, i'm sure. I also ask user on which way was file deleted but on usually way, right click -> delete

Comment: Because he says reight click > delete so Maybe the has been deleted from file explorer as shift delete ! I suggest to go to him and let you delete a dummy file as he delete the old one to check his scenario in details

Comment: Thank you M.Qassas for your effort. I'm sure in everything what I was wrote.  But, now I was looking on user side and see that's cause is that I really can't see deleted users files because when I logged on as different user then I can see that file. Now I'm, confused because I have admin rights, why I than can't see this and how to fix this ???

Comment: this is the second point I mentioned above  > Recycle Bin is not only site-specific, it is also specific for each user. Thus the Recycle Bin contents you see is limited to documents, items, lists and libraries that you’ve deleted, content deleted by other users does not show up here as I think.

Comment: I later saw that maybe I'm admin but I'm not set as admin in Site Collection administrators and there was problem. 
Yes, this answer was very useful for me and solved my problem, thank you M.Qassas .

Answer (score 0):

You should check the settings in Central Administration to see if the recycle bin is actually activated or not.

Comment: Can you please add some more details about how that is done?

Comment: Don't understand you, sorry... If you mean how is sharepoint designed, I dont know.  It's old, only recently where outside company upgraded him to 2013. I'm new at all in the firm and in sharepoint.